# A Productive Javascript/Phonegap Development Environment

Tags: javascript, cordova, ide, production-environment

I've been building **Android** apps for a few years now, and I've arrived to this working setup:

- Intellij Idea IDE write/debug
- Genymotion "Emulator"
- Physical Device (only when needed)
- Git
- Ant (probably should move to Gradle) Release/Debug builds

And now I'm looking to form an equally productive environment for **Javascript** (Phonegap, etc), for Android/iOS/Win8Phone.

I want to **avoid** the "nice-text-editor-only" solution (I believe a full IDE is superior in productivity terms).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just want to clarify, you want to avoid the need to constantly switch between your code editor and Chrome for debugging?

Comment: I meant to avoid a text-editor-only solution, I'm looking for a full IDE (will edit the question now)

Comment: You should try Adobe Brackets, as mentioned by Pradyumna. It has a live development mode which integrates into Chrome. Anything you type into Brackets is reflected instantly into the browser, this set up works great if you have 2 screens.

Comment: Thankz James for mentioning my name...and adding extra information regarding Brackets for easier understanding...

Answer (score 0):

Try Brackets editor http://brackets.io/. It's a nice editor to code the web. Phonegap plugins also available for this editor. Just take a look at this editor. Make sure to download the version of Brackets with Phonegap Plugin compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cordova/Phonegap app I developed, I used cloud9. In my workflow, I would first get things working in my browser, then occasionally do builds with Adobe's Phonegap Build service to work out the kinks on my mobile devices.
The nice thing about c9 is you'll have a public URL for the website you're developing so you can preview it in your device's browser, which is typically closer to the environment you'll get with Phonegap.

The weinre debugging tool, although slow if you're running it through http://debug.phonegap.com/, can really help track down problems when debugging on mobile devices.